# Is it an antipattern to have a normalized Kafka Producer Microservice for several topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wanting to implement a Kafka GraphQL Microservice that would produce to several topics. This microservice would serve as a service that other microservices could easily send messages to. Each request to this producer microservice would contain the topic that it wants to publish to and the payload associated to that topic. In my mind this is a more streamlined approach than having every service that wants to publish to a topic have kafka library code and any other boilerplate code associated with being able to produce to a topic. All the Kafka-specific logic would live in the producer service reducing the amount of duplicated code across services.

Answer (score 2):

Not an anti-pattern at all. The Producer is also thread-safe.

Confluent's Kafka REST Proxy already does this by giving an array of partition+record objects to the endpoint

`POST /clusters/{cluster_id}/topics/{topic_name}/records`

Docs - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#records-v3

---

However, depending on your use-case, I'd suggest implementing GraphQL resolvers with topics already hard-coded for the specific events you want to generate rather than user-supplied. In other words, prevent bad actors from populating any random topic with random data.

---

> In my mind this is a more streamlined approach than having every service that wants to publish to a topic have kafka library code and any other boilerplate code associated with being able to produce to a topic

That "boilerplate" could be an external library on its own, such as autowired Spring-Kafka Beans

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm just trying to understand the trade-offs for this architectural decision. If I go the GraphQL producer service route, I gain the benefit of Schema discovery, an easy-to-use endpoint for other services trying to produce messages to Kafka, but what I lose is performance and I create a single point of failure. Is there anything else I'm not considering?

Comment: And yes I'm also thinking about using a library instead that would contain all of my models that are required for the topics that I'm trying to publish as well as the boilerplate code required to produce a Kafka topic. With that route, I wouldn't take a big performance hit, and I get the benefit of keeping the code clean.

Comment: I've seen both approaches. Particularly where there are client HTTP services (frontend sites, or mobile clients for example) that cannot embed Kafka clients themselves. Not any different answer than traditional 3-tier system, really... Regarding schema discovery, various Schema Registry projects already exist for Kafka. I've not seen one that offers GraphQL integration/generation, however...